# De-block method if we can control where the "block" artifact to appear

Tags: algorithm, image-processing

I am working on a patch-wise method to process image. So the result suffer from block-y artifact.

Current commonly available methods(or just what I can find) are focusing on single compressed image like jpeg and try to de-block their artifact and reconstruct a clear version of them.

However, I have full control to decide where the block-y artifact to appear.

For example if we have a image with dimension (16, 16), and we have a patch size of (8, 8), then 4 block-y artifacts will appear as a line between patches as following:

```
.x→0123456789012345...
y  image A
↓
0  ////////\\\\\\\\
1  ////////\\\\\\\\
2  ////////\\\\\\\\
3  ////////\\\\\\\\
4  ////1///\\\\2\\\
5  ////////\\\\\\\\
6  ////////\\\\\\\\
7  ////////\\\\\\\\
8  \\\\\\\\////////
9  \\\\\\\\////////
0  \\\\\\\\////////
1  \\\\3\\\///4////
2  \\\\\\\\////////
3  \\\\\\\\////////
4  \\\\\\\\////////
5  \\\\\\\\////////
```

And by saying "I have full control of the block." It means I can pre-pad the image with zero-s half the width and height of the patch size. So the resulting 9 block-y artifacts will be:

```
.x→0123456789012345...                   .x→0123456789012345...
y                                        y  image B
↓                                        ↓
0  0000000000000000                      0  1+++***2****+++3
1  0000000000000000                      1  ++++********++++
2  0000000000000000                      2  ++++********++++
3  0000000000000000                      3  ++++********++++
4  00001+++***2****     remove padding   4  ****++++++++****
5  0000++++********           →          5  ****++++++++****
6  0000++++********                      6  ****++++++++****
7  0000++++********                      7  4***++++5+++***6
8  0000****++++++++                      8  ****++++++++****
9  0000****++++++++                      9  ****++++++++****
0  0000****++++++++                      0  ****++++++++****
1  00004***++++5+++                      1  ****++++++++****
2  0000****++++++++                      2  ++++********++++
3  0000****++++++++                      3  ++++********++++
4  0000****++++++++                      4  ++++********++++
5  0000****++++++++                      5  7+++***8****+++9
```

As the "lines" in image B are now off-set by 4 and sit right between the lines appear in image A.

Here comes the real question. Does there are any algorithm to de-block the image by A and B together?

My first naive thought is to make check-like rhombus mask and then combine the two images. So the result will be:

```
.x→0123456789012345...                   .x→0123456789012345...
y  image A and B                         y  
↓                                        ↓
0  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA                      0  ////////\\\\\\\\
1  AAAAAAABBAAAAAAA                      1  ///////**\\\\\\\
2  AAAAAABBBBAAAAAA                      2  //////****\\\\\\
3  AAAAABBBBBBAAAAA                      3  /////******\\\\\
4  AAAABBBBBBBBAAAA                      4  ////++++++++\\\\
5  AAABBBBBBBBBBAAA                      5  ///*++++++++*\\\
6  AABBBBBBBBBBBBAA                      6  //**++++++++**\\
7  ABBBBBBBBBBBBBBA                      7  /***++++++++***\
8  ABBBBBBBBBBBBBBA                      8  \***++++++++***/
9  AABBBBBBBBBBBBAA                      9  \\**++++++++**//
0  AAABBBBBBBBBBAAA                      0  \\\*++++++++*///
1  AAAABBBBBBBBAAAA                      1  \\\\********////
2  AAAAABBBBBBAAAAA                      2  \\\\\******/////
3  AAAAAABBBBAAAAAA                      3  \\\\\\****//////
4  AAAAAAABBAAAAAAA                      4  \\\\\\\**///////
5  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA                      5  \\\\\\\\////////
```

And then I realize this will not erase the artifact but became another smaller block (if we assume the edge between A and B are smooth) as following:

```
.x→0123456789012345...
y  finale image
↓
0  ****************
1  ****************
2  ****************
3  ****************
4  ***––––––––––***
5  ***∣*********∣***
6  ***∣*********∣***
7  ***∣*********∣***
8  ***∣*********∣***
9  ***∣*********∣***
0  ***∣*********∣***
1  ***––––––––––***
2  ****************
3  ****************
4  ****************
5  ****************
```

So I was like "c'mon, there must be a better way" and came here looking for help.